# How to join three tables with eloquent using a model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've never studied Eloquent.  I am studying APIs and I want to get some data as kickly as possible, without writing sql, what is I usually do.

I have the tables: "house" related to "announcement" (one to one) and the "announcement" table is related to "advertiser" (one to many).

When I tried

```
       $house = \App\House::where('house_id', $id)->with('announcement', 'advertiser')->first();
```

I get the error:  announcement undefined method.
I think I set up the relationship on the models correctly so I didn't include them here. I want to join using the model House because I am not using the default connection when using Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**with()** must be placed at first, and specify your relationships in an array (if you load more than one)

```
$house = \App\House::with(['announcement', 'advertiser'])->where('house_id', $id)->first();
```

**Edit :**
Sorry, i haven't seen that it's a nested relationship
You can use this code instead of the above one :

```
$house = \App\House::with(['announcement', 'announcement.advertiser'])->where('house_id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: generated BadMethodCallException :Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::advertiser()

Comment: My bad, it seems to be a nested relationship. I`ve edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

for a nested relationship use dot like announcement.advertiser

`$house = App\House::with(['announcement', 'announcement.advertiser'])->where('house_id', $id)->first();`